# Task manager with latex typesetting

Tags: tools

What kind of solutions do you use for personal task management that support latex typesetting?

Beside off-the-shelf apps, if they exist (e.g. todoist-like app with latex support), it would be nice to know of other creative solutions, like a jupyter plugin or a wikimedia personal task manager extension or whatever.

Initial ideas:

- Adding \todo to latex docs and grepping them.
- clickup.com (hoping they add latex in the future). Brilliant documentation and task management features, but no latex.
- dropbox paper, as it has some math typesetting. But the task management features are meager.
- Jupyter notebooks(/lab). Great latex and documentation support, but to task management features.

Comment: Emacs with org mode!

Comment: org-mode is nice, but can emacs display latex inline? (auctex?) 
regardless, emacs is not very friendly, i.e., it has a (very) steep learning curve (even if one was already acquainted with it a while back).
I had something a little more modern in mind.